Bounding the entropy of an $M$-state random variable.
I am a little bit confused with the following proof:

$$H(x) = -\sum_{i=1}^Mp(x_i)\ln p(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^Mp(x_i)\ln \frac{1}{p(x_i)}.$$
It is then said that since $\ln x$ is concave we can reverse Jensen's inequality to obtain:
$$\sum_{i=1}^Mp(x_i)\ln \frac{1}{p(x_i)} \leq \ln \sum_{i=1}^M\frac{p(x_i)}{p(x_i)} = \ln M.$$

I don't understand this. The function $\ln \frac{1}{p(x_i)} = -\ln p(x_i) $ is convex.
My attempt at proving this is not really going anywhere:
Using Jensen's inequality:
$$H(x) \geq - \ln \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^M p(x_i)^2 \bigg]$$
Note that $$\sum_{i=1}^M p(x_i)^2 \leq M \implies - \ln \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^M p(x_i)^2 \bigg] \geq -\ln M,$$
since $-\ln$ is decreasing. So I am left with
$$H(x) \geq -\ln M$$
Is there a way to "fix" my proof?

We are not using convexity of $x \mapsto \ln \frac1x$, but concavity of $x \mapsto \ln x$. (We want a concave function, because we want an upper bound on the sum and not a lower bound.)
The function $x \mapsto \ln x$ is concave for all $x \ge 0$, so when $p_1, \dots, p_M \ge 0$, $p_1 + \dots + p_M = 1$, and $x_1, \dots, x_M \ge 0$, Jensen's inequality tells us that $$\ln(p_1 x_1 + \dots + p_M x_M) \ge p_1 \ln(x_1) + \dots + p_M \ln(x_M).$$ I wrote this with arbitrary $x_1,\dots,x_M$ to begin with, but now we are going to set $x_i = \frac1{p_i}$ for all $i$. This gives us $$\ln\left(p_1 \cdot \frac1{p_1} + \dots + p_M \cdot \frac1{p_M}\right) \ge p_1 \ln\left(\frac1{p_1}\right) + \dots + p_M \ln\left(\frac1{p_M}\right).$$ On the left-hand side, the sum $p_1 \cdot \frac1{p_1} + \dots + p_M \cdot \frac1{p_M}$ simplifies to $1 + 1 + \dots + 1 = M$, so the left-hand side is equal to $\ln M$. On the right-hand side, we have exactly the entropy of $X$. Therefore $H(X) \le \ln M$.
